# problemas al subir una app en PHP a hosting no pasa del login y arroja errores

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, hosting

tengo un problema, desarrollé una aplicación web en PHP principalmente, de manera local trabaja excelente, el login tiene niveles de usuarios y agregué recién captcha; al subirla al hosting, en este caso 000webhost  no funciona, no pasa del login y al ver cada archivo manda errores. 
hice lo siguiente:

- Subi todos los archivos a public_html
- subi base de datos
- cambié user, password y nombre de BD por lo que el hosting me generó

Al intentar hacer login me envía echo de que las credenciales son incorrectas. - si estoy ingresando el password correcto -  pensé en utilizar este hosting porque hace poco subí una web estática y todo bien y pensé en hacerlo de nuevo, es tarea que tengo que presentar, no me interesa escalar después el proyecto.

[image: vista Clientes]

El código de esa vista es este:   agregué como comentario el número de línea, disculpen si no se como agregarlo bien.

```html
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['nivel']!='administrador'){
    header('location:index.php');
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css"/>
        <title>Cliente</title>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>       
<script>
function buscarCliente(identificador){
    var getUrl = window.location;
    var baseUrl = getUrl.protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
    var identificador = identificador;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: 'identificador='+identificador,
        url: baseUrl+'/Operaciones/buscarCliente.php',
        success: function(data){
    $('#identificador').val(identificador);
    $('#nomCliente').val(data.nomCliente);
    $('#appCliente').val(data.appCliente);
    $('#apmCliente').val(data.apmCliente);
    $('#alcalCliente').val(data.alcalCliente);
    $('#colCliente').val(data.colCliente);
    $('#calleCliente').val(data.calleCliente);
    $('#nextCliente').val(data.nextCliente);
    $('#nintCliente').val(data.nintCliente);
    $('#telCliente').val(data.telCliente);
    $('#mailCliente').val(data.mailCliente);
    $('#txtfpago').val(data.fPago);
    $('#descserv').val(data.tipoServ);
    $('#fechaServ').val(data.fechaServ);
    $('#marca').val(data.marca);
    $('#memRam').val(data.memRam);
    $('#dd').val(data.dd);
    $('#procesador').val(data.procesador);
    $('#detalles').val(data.detalles);
    $('#desprods').val(data.alta);
    $('#form-registro').attr('action', 'Operaciones/actualizarCliente.php');
    $('#form-button').val("Actualizar");
        }
    });
}
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
      <img src="imagenes/headerclientes.png" width="800" height="95"/> <!-- header-->
      <br>
      <hr noshade size="15" color = "#C0C0C0">
      <div id="menu"> <!--barra de menu-->
          <ul>
              <li><a href="administrador.php">Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a href="catProductos.php">Catálogo productos</a></li>
              <li><a href="catServicios.php">Catálogo servicios</a></li>
              <li><a href="catPago.php">Catálogo pago</a></li>
              <li><a href="empleados.php">Empleados</a></li>
              <li><a href="clientes.php">Clientes</a></li>
              <li><a href="servicios.php">Servicios</a></li>              
                 
              <li><a href="salir.php">Salir</a></li>           
          </ul>
      </div>
      <br>
      
       <div id="formcliente"> <!--formulario clientes-->
           <form id="form-registro" action="operaciones/guardarCliente.php" method ="POST"> 
            <input type="hidden" id="identificador" name="identificador" value="">
            <label>Datos Cliente</label>
            <br>
            <br> 
           
            <input type="text" REQUIRED pattern="[a-zA-z áéíóúñüàè]+" id="nomCliente" name="nomCliente" placeholder="Nombre..." value=""/><br><br>                  
            <input type="text" REQUIRED pattern="[a-zA-z áéíóúñüàè]+" id="appCliente" name="appCliente" placeholder="Apellido Paterno..." value=""/><br><br>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED pattern="[a-zA-z áéíóúñüàè]+" id="apmCliente" name="apmCliente" placeholder="Apellido Materno..." value=""/><br><br>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED  id="alcalCliente" name="alcalCliente" placeholder="Alcaldía..." value=""/><br><br>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED id="colCliente" name="colCliente" placeholder="Colonia..." value=""/><br><br>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED id="calleCliente" name="calleCliente" placeholder="Calle..." value=""/><br><br>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED id="nextCliente" name="nextCliente" placeholder="No Exterior..." value=""/><br><br>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED id="nintCliente" name="nintCliente" placeholder="No Interior..." value=""/><br><br>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED pattern="[0-9]+" id="telCliente" name="telCliente" placeholder="Teléfono..." value=""/><br><br>                                  
            <input type="email" REQUIRED id="mailCliente" name="mailCliente" placeholder="Mail..." value=""/><br><br>
             <?php
            
            include('operaciones/conexion.php');    //---------esta es la línea 90---------
            $txtfpago="";
            if(isset($_POST['TXTFPAGO'])) {
                $txtfpago=$_POST['TXTFPAGO'];
            }
           
            
            $strSQL="select idfpago, fpago from fpago ";
            
            
            $respuesta2= $conexion->query($strSQL);     //---------esta es la línea 100---------
            
            $strfpago="";
            
            while($row=$respuesta2->fetch_assoc()) {
            // llenar strcombo
              if($txtfpago == $row['fpago']) {
   // SI ES IGUAL
   $strfpago = $strfpago . "<option value = '".$row['idfpago']."' selected='selected'>".$row['fpago']."</option> ";
  } else {
   // NO ES IGUAL 
   $strfpago .= "<option value = '".$row['idfpago']."' >".$row['fpago']."</option> ";
  }
                
            }
            ?>

            <label>Forma de Pago</label> <br> <!--select forma de pago-->
            <br>
           <select id="txtfpago" name="txtfpago">
               <?php
                echo($strfpago);
               ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <?php
            // bloque servicio
            $txtserv="";
            if(isset($_POST['txtserv'])) {
                $txtserv=$_POST['txtserv'];
            }
            $txtserv="";
            
            
            $strSQL="select idserv,descripcion from serv ";
            
            
            $respuesta2= $conexion->query($strSQL);
            
            $strserv="";
            
            while($row=$respuesta2->fetch_assoc()) {
            // llenar strcombo
              if($txtserv == $row['descripcion']) {
   // SI ES IGUAL
   $strserv = $strserv . "<option value = '".$row['idserv']."' selected='selected'>".$row['descripcion']."</option> ";
  } else {
   // NO ES IGUAL 
   $strserv .= "<option value = '".$row['idserv']."' >".$row['descripcion']."</option> ";
  }
                
            }
            ?>

            <label>Tipo de Servicio</label> <br>
            <select id="descserv" name="descserv">
               <?php
                echo($strserv);
               ?>
             </select>
            
            
            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="date" REQUIRED id="fechaServ" name="fechaServ" placeholder="Fecha de Servicio YYYY-MM-DD..." value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>"/><br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>Máquina</label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED id="marca" name="marca" placeholder="Marca de la Máquina" value=""/><br><br>                  
            <input type="text" REQUIRED id="memRam" name="memRam" placeholder="Memoria RAM..." value=""/><br><br>               
            <input type="text" REQUIRED id="dd" name="dd" placeholder="Capacidad Disco Duro..." value=""/><br><br>                                  
            <input type="text" REQUIRED id="procesador" name="procesador" placeholder="Procesador..." value=""/><br><br>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED id="detalles" name="detalles" placeholder="Detalles.." value=""/><br><br>
            
             <?php
            
            // bloque productos
            $txtprods="";
            if(isset($_POST['txtprods'])) {
                $txtprods=$_POST['txtprods'];
            }
            $txtprods="";
            
            
            $strSQL="select idprods, descripcion from prods ";
            
            
            $respuesta2= $conexion->query($strSQL);
            
            $strprods="";
            
            while($row=$respuesta2->fetch_assoc()) {
            // llenar strcombo
              if($txtprods == $row['descripcion']) {
   // SI ES IGUAL
   $strprods = $strprods . "<option value = '".$row['idprods']."' selected='selected'>".$row['descripcion']."</option> ";
  } else {
   // NO ES IGUAL 
   $strprods .= "<option value = '".$row['idprods']."' >".$row['descripcion']."</option>";
  }
                
            }
            ?>
            
            <label>Productos</label> <br> <!-- select productos-->
            <select id="desprods" name="desprods">
               <?php
                echo($strprods);
               ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>

            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="form-button" value="Guardar"/>             
        </form>    
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <table width="100%" border="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse"> <!--tabla que muestra registros-->
            <thead>
                <tr class="listatit">
                    <th colspan="21">Listado de Clientes Y Servicios</th>  
                </tr>
            
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="menutab">
                    <td>ID</td>  
                    <td>Cliente </td>
                    <td>Teléfono</td>
                    <td>Mail </td> 
                    <td>Forma de Pago </td>
                    <td>Tipo de Servicio</td>
                    <td>Fecha Servicio</td>
                    <td>Marca Máquina</td>
                      
                    <td>Procesador</td>
                    <td>Detalles</td>
                    
                    <td colspan="2">Operaciones </td>    
                </tr>
    <?php
        //include("Operaciones/conexion.php"); //conexion base de datos
        //$query="SELECT * from clientes,servicios,maquina,pago,fpago, serv WHERE pago.id_cliente = clientes.idCliente AND servicios.id_cliente = clientes.idCliente AND maquina.id_cliente = clientes.idCliente AND serv.idserv=servicios.tipoServ AND fpago.idfpago=pago.fPago"; //consulta antigua
        $query="SELECT * from clientes,servicios,maquina,pago,fpago, serv WHERE pago.id_cliente = clientes.idCliente AND servicios.id_cliente = clientes.idCliente AND maquina.id_cliente = clientes.idCliente AND serv.idserv=servicios.tipoServ AND fpago.idfpago=pago.fPago";
        //echo("<br> SQL: ".$query."<br");
        
        $respuesta= $conexion->query($query);//pasando consulta
                $txtfpago=$row['fpago'];
                $txtserv=$row['descserv'];
                $txtprods=$row['desprods'];
                
            
        while($row=$respuesta->fetch_assoc()){ //guarda en arreglo
    ?>   
                
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['nomCliente'].' '.$row['appCliente'].' '.$row['apmCliente']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['telCliente']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['mailCliente']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['fpago']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['descripcion']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo date( "d-m-Y",strtotime($row['fechaServ'])); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['marca']; ?></td>
            <!-- Aqui iba memoria RAM y abajo Disco duro, eliminé por cuestiones de espacio en tabla-->
            <td> <?php echo $row['procesador']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['detalles']; ?></td>
               <!aqui va empleado asignado-->   
            
            <td> <button id="modificar" onclick="javascript:buscarCliente(<?php echo $row['idCliente'];?>);">Modificar</button></td>
            <td> <a id="vinculo" href="Operaciones/eliminaCliente.php?idCliente=<?php echo $row['idCliente'];?>">Eliminar</a> </td>
                    
        </tr>    
                
    <?php    
        }
    ?>
                
            </tbody>  
        </table>
      <br><br>  
    </body>
</html>
```

el login es este y de ahí no paso a pesar de introducir las credenciales correctas

https://acysapp.000webhostapp.com/

disculpen esto tan largo, pero no se como resolverlo, es la primera vez que subo una app a un hosting, gracias de antemano.

así tengo las carpetas...... ya cambié operaciones con O Mayúscula, pero aún sigue sin dejarme pasar del login,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puede abrir el archivo `operaciones/conexion.php`

Comment: Hola @Cinthya, ¿Cómo tienes la estructura de carpetas y donde está ubicado el directorio operaciones ?

Comment: Tu fallo esta aqui: include('operaciones/conexion.php');    //---------esta es la línea 90--------- Esta codigo implica que estas incluyendo un archivo conexion.php que esta dentro de una carpeta operaciones que esta al mismo nivel que este fichero php desde donde lo incluyes. Pon bien la ruta relativa, recuerda .. para volver hacia atras.

Comment: El error está en que el directorio `Operaciones` en el servidor empieza en mayúsculas y en tu código en minúsculas. Muy probablemente el hosting sea un linux, el cual es sensible a mayúsculas, a diferencia de Windows que no, y por eso si te funciona localmente.

Comment: Prueba a include('Operaciones/conexion.php') en vez de include('operaciones/conexion.php'), ví que la carpeta tiene la O en mayúscula.

Comment: Posiblemente tengas muchas más cosas que cambiar. Por ejemplo, en el código que pusiste, hay una parte JS que dice `url: baseUrl+'/Operaciones/buscarCliente.php'`, aquí el llamado al directorio si está en mayúscula. Tienes que corregir eso en TODOS los scripts del sitio. Y lo mismo pasa con la Base De Datos y sus tablas, verifica que todas tengan exactamente el mismo nombre mayúscula o minúscula.